# Forgot answer...now what?

Tags: discussion

I have forgotten the answer to [one of my puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74003/i-am-happier-now). What do I do?

I find it quite remarkable that a similar post doesn't already exist here.

Comment: Quite a conundrum! It might be easier if you linked to the puzzle in question. I assume it's [**this one**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81689/no-time-for-an-emperor)?

Comment: Nice try Brandon, lol! Actually it's this one: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/74003/i-am-happier-now/87926#87926 although I've remembered some part of it

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, **come clean about it**. As you've done here on meta, but maybe add a comment to the question along the lines of "oops, I've forgotten the answer to my own puzzle". It *is* allowed to post a puzzle where the OP doesn't know the answer, as for example in our [real](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real) tag, but it should always be made clear that that's the case. People trying to solve the problem should be aware that they may not be able to find a solution or it may not be verifiable.

We have a pretty smart puzzle-solving community. Maybe someone will post an answer that jogs your memory and helps you to remember your solution!

You mentioned in a comment here that you remember "some part of" the solution. Maybe, if it goes unsolved for a long time, you could **post a partial answer** yourself with what you do remember? This is a very tentative suggestion, as it depends a lot on exactly what you do remember. But that answer might, again, help someone else to get the full solution and jog your memory.